# MySQL query conditional return using TRIM()

Tags: mysql

I am trying to SELECT from a table, but I need to trim from leading and trailing string for comparison. For example,

My table/data is very simple

```
CREATE TABLE `lcr` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `prefix` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `digits` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

mysql> select * from lcr;
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| id | prefix | digits | price  |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
|  1 | 1122   | 92300  | 0.0198 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am running the following select

```
SELECT * FROM `lcr` WHERE `digits` IN ((SELECT (TRIM(LEADING '1122' FROM '112292300'))), (SELECT (TRIM(LEADING '1122' FROM '11229230'))), (SELECT (TRIM(LEADING '1122' FROM '1122923'))), (SELECT (TRIM(LEADING '1122' FROM '112292'))))
```

which trims the leading 1122 from digits, and gives a positive match. But when I run the query

```
SELECT * FROM `lcr` WHERE `digits` IN ((SELECT (TRIM(LEADING '1122' FROM '92300'))), (SELECT (TRIM(LEADING '1122' FROM '9230'))), (SELECT (TRIM(LEADING '1122' FROM '923'))), (SELECT (TRIM(LEADING '1122' FROM '92'))))
```

I also get a positive match. Because Trim is actually not doing anything and in my table, digits are 92300.

Is there a way we can use some sort of condition or if function or something like that which should only return the result if prefix+trim = actual data passed?

I may not be much expressive asking my question here, so apologize for that and let me know if there is any info required to answer my question.

Thanks.

Comment: But still not sure how you determine, then. Let me ask a different way. When you get '112292300', how do you determine that '1122' is the prefix and not '11' or '11229'?

Answer (score 1):

I am reading between the lines a bit, based on the table name 'lcr', which I assume has to do with the "least cost routing" of telephone traffic.  Having been a telephone engineer prior to becoming a DBA, the question is interesting to me on a couple of levels.

What you have not actually stated -- but I am assuming -- based on portions of your question where you were using shorter and shorter patterns -- is that the query could result in more than one match, depending on the combinations of digits seen... but to you, there is one "ideal" choice for any input value.

Which choice that is depends on how you've filled your data.  I've seen tables of prefixes where the rule was that you always wanted to route on the longest, most-specific match (maximum number of digits matched) because the table only included more-specific entries when the rates were better at specific deeper levels in the hierarchy.

On the other hand, if you have all possible routes and rates in your table, then you would want to go with *any* valid match, as long as all of the digits matched, but you would want to prioritize by cost, because a longer digit-pattern-match would not, necessarily, mean a lower cost in that case.

Illustration:

```
query prefix digits
 513    5      1      this is a match, but it is not the most specific match
 513    5      13     this is a match, and is more specific match than '5+1'
 513    5      130    not a match for the input query '513', because not every '513X' has X = 0 -- too specific
```

In the example above, if the query were actually '5130' then 5 + 130 would also be a valid match.

The logical expression for this is condition seems relatively straightforward:

```
WHERE LEFT(my_query,LENGTH(CONCAT(prefix,digits))) = CONCAT(prefix,digits)
```

That is, given the length *n* of the combined string of prefix plus digits, the leftmost *n* digits of the input query need to match, exactly, the string prefix+digits, and prefix+digits must be the same length as the original query, or shorter.

This would match all combinations in the table where the leftmost digits of the input query were identical to the combination of (prefix,digits) without going over.

If you wanted the longest match, that would mean adding this...

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(CONCAT(prefix,digits)) DESC
```

Or, if you wanted the lowest-cost match, that would mean adding this...

```
ORDER BY price ASC
```

...finally we presumably only care about the first (longest, or cheapest) result, which means adding this...

```
LIMIT 1;
```

So, from the logical perspective, those three lines together become the `WHERE` that matches, the `ORDER BY` that returns the best match first (using one or the other `ORDER` but not both), and the `LIMIT` that relieves the DBMS of having to provide you with more rows than will actually be useful.

Unfortunately, from a database perspective, this is not going to be a well-performing query if your data is of any significant size.  In fact, as a DBA, this is the sort of query that would give me nightmares, because every time the query is run, it is going to tend toward using a full table scan, "Using temporary, Using filesort" ... with no indexes being useful for resolving the query.

Consider the contrast between these two logically-equivalent expressions.  Assuming you had an index on (some_column), which was a `DATETIME`:

```
WHERE DATE(some_column) = '2013-11-19';                           # terrible performance
WHERE some_column >= '2013-11-19' AND some_colummn < '2013-11-20'; # excellent performace
```

The first query is terrible, because the server has to evaluate `DATE()` against that column in each row, for every row in the table, and return the ones that evaluated to the constant literal '2013-11-19'.

The second is excellent, since the server can simply scan the index range between 2013-11-19 00:00:00 inclusive and 2013-11-20 exclusive and *voilà‎* the index returns exactly the matching rows.

There is no analog for this with your current structure.  The only logically-valid expression that I can come up with that returns the precise result you need... is not [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) at all.

But if my assumptions are correct about the logic, so far, then you might consider how well the query performs against the full data set to see if you need to optimize it further.  It might be that the data set is small enough that you could use the `MEMORY` storage engine or that your server has enough memory and this table has enough traffic that it would stay resident in the buffer pool or cache, that it just might work.

If not, consider another, also seemingly-unorthodox, but very practical addition to the query.

If the shortest possible prefix that could ever match is 1 digit, you could add this to the where clause:

```
AND prefix LIKE CONCAT(LEFT(my_query,1),'%')
```

Or two digits...

```
AND prefix LIKE CONCAT(LEFT(my_query,2),'%')
```

Or three...

You may be thinking "that will match too many prefixes."  Yes, it will... but, if there is an index on the (prefix) column, then the optimizer should, at least sometimes, choose to go to the index to find only the rows with a prefix that "could possibly" match, and then apply the rest of the logic (above) to narrow down the precise match.  This means the "full table scan" is reducible to what might be a significantly smaller subset of the table, and since the `AND` conditions must all be true, using this should be more optimum than not.

In fact, as long as the integer you use as the second argument to `LEFT()` is the same as the length as the shortest prefix in the table, it will still work, because a wildcard will also "match" nothing at all.

```
mysql> select 'foo' like 'foo%';
+-------------------+
| 'foo' like 'foo%' |
+-------------------+
|                 1 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you are looking for the lowest-cost valid match, then I would also add an index on (price), because the optimizer could choose to scan the table in order by ascending price, evaluating the other expressions against each row it encounters, and stopping after the first match, because that would satisfy the `ORDER BY` and the `LIMIT 1`.

You should test with various inputs, using `EXPLAIN SELECT` to see the query plan, because the plan will vary based on the table data as well as the input query, since the optimizer can make different decisions on a per-query basis depending on which approach it believes will allow it to do the least amount of work while still arriving at the same, correct answer.

In all of the exmaples, I have used the identifier 'my_query' as a placeholder for the input value.  This might be a variable like `@my_query` or program variable like `my_query`  in a stored procedure or function, or a position placeholder `?` in a prepared statement, or the just literal value you're trying to match.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow. Not sure if this will hit the spot, but have to say this is possibly the most beautiful answer I have seen on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM `lcr` 
WHERE `digits` Like '1122%'
  AND `digits` IN (SELECT (TRIM(LEADING '1122' FROM '112292300')
```

Comment: Can not because the input I get from the user is 112292300, so I have no way of knowing what is the prefix until I find the prefix out of the string.

Comment: But you find it out the prefix to include in the LEADING clause, no? Can you not use the same technique to populate the LIKE? :-(

Comment: @Goni how do you determine what the prefix is. They give you '112292300'? And you determine that the prefix is '1122' because it's is the first four characters? Or matches some pattern? Or...?

Comment: That's the problem. I can't know from the incoming number what's the prefix. It can be 1 or more than 1 characters. This is what I am trying to figure out here, how to strip ONLY the prefix, and select only PREFIX + DIGITS.

Answer (score 0):

@michael-sqlbot Must say, that was a very nice and detailed reply. Appreciate that. However we have been doing quite a few things to run the LCR setup properly.

Come back to my question, the answer was rather much simpler.

```
SELECT * FROM `lcr` WHERE `digits` IN ((SELECT (TRIM(LEADING '1122' FROM '92300'))), (SELECT (TRIM(LEADING '1122' FROM '9230'))), (SELECT (TRIM(LEADING '1122' FROM '923'))), (SELECT (TRIM(LEADING '1122' FROM '92'))))
```

Since we need to match against the PREFIX + DIGITS, so the solution was actually to use a **CONCAT (`prefix`, `digits`)** which fixed the query :)

```
SELECT * FROM `lcr` WHERE CONCAT (`prefix`, `digits`) IN ((SELECT (TRIM(LEADING '1122' FROM '92300'))), (SELECT (TRIM(LEADING '1122' FROM '9230'))), (SELECT (TRIM(LEADING '1122' FROM '923'))), (SELECT (TRIM(LEADING '1122' FROM '92'))))
```